# Why can't i align the div that contains text next to the div that contains the image

Tags: html, css

i'm currently working on a webpage for my design class and i have a problem. This is the browser view:

[image: browser view]

I am kinda new with html and css but i have tried display in-line block, flex... Nothing worked, and i dont know what else i could do

So the problem is that the text "aaaaa" must be next to image. Here is my html code:

```css
.caixa {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 70%;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 25px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.caixa-img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 15%;
  position: relative;
}

.caixa-img img {
  margin-right: 120px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.info {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.tipo {}

.descripcio {
  display: block;
  background-color: chartreuse;
}

.tipo a {
  color: #222222;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.tipo span {
  color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.5);
}

.preu {
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-family: poppins;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(226, 197, 88, 0.6);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.comprar {
  width: 160px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #252525;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.comprar:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: rgb(248, 171, 55);
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.overlay {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.caixa-img:hover .overlay {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: fade 0.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 productes">
  <div class="producte1">
    <div class="caixa">

      <div class="caixa-img">
        <img alt="" src="imgExplora/imgCarrousel/herbicida.jpg">

        <div class="overlay">

          <a href="#" class="comprar">Comprar</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tipo">
          <a href="#">
            <h3>HERBICIDA</h3>
          </a>
          <!--
                                        <div class="rating">
                                            <span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span>
                                        </div>-->
        </div>

        <a href="#" class="preu">55€</a>

      </div>

      <div class="info">

        <span class="descripcio">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below an example using flexbox (see `.caixa`).

```css
.caixa {
  width: 70%;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 25px 25px 25px 0;
  /* margin-left: 0px; */
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex; /* Added */
}

.caixa-img {
  margin: 15px;
  width: 30%;
}

.caixa-img img {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 125px; /* For demo */
  height: 125px; /* For demo */
}

.info {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.tipo {}

.descripcio {
  display: block;
  background-color: chartreuse;
  word-break: break-all; /* Essential to break large words */
}

.tipo a {
  color: #222222;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.tipo span {
  color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.5);
}

.preu {
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-family: poppins;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(226, 197, 88, 0.6);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.comprar {
  width: 160px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #252525;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.comprar:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: rgb(248, 171, 55);
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.overlay {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.caixa-img:hover .overlay {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: fade 0.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 productes">
  <div class="producte1">
    <div class="caixa">
      <div class="caixa-img">
        <img alt="" src="imgExplora/imgCarrousel/herbicida.jpg">
        <div class="overlay">
          <a href="#" class="comprar">Comprar</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tipo">
          <a href="#">
            <h3>HERBICIDA</h3>
          </a>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="preu">55€</a>
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <span class="descripcio">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                            aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use boostrap framework
you can use the bootstrap column and row.

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 productes">
      <div class="producte1">
        <div class="caixa">
          <div class="caixa-img">
            <img alt="" src="imgExplora/imgCarrousel/herbicida.jpg">
            <div class="overlay">
              <a href="#" class="comprar">Comprar</a>
            </div>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
            <div class="tipo">
              <a href="#">
                <h3>HERBICIDA</h3>
              </a>
              <!--
                                            <div class="rating">
                                                <span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span>
                                            </div>-->
            </div>

            <a href="#" class="preu">55€</a>

          </div>

          <div class="info">

            <span class="descripcio">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                            aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>


          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You have too much nested `divs` that dont need to be there, just making it more complex.

Also, your text is going outside your `div` borders, this is not a good thing.

You can move your text next to the image by using `flex`.

You always apply `flex` on a parent of the element that you want to move around (in this case, div with a picture, and div with a text).

So you are going to apply `flex` to a `div` that holds both of those `divs` (div with image, and div with text).

Here is my solution to this problem on a simple example, it should help you :

https://codepen.io/Juka99/pen/YzGVQyv

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i will check my code and try to optimize it :) your apport was very usefull for me.